# Cannot retrieve process.env variable with NextJS app hosted on Fargate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, next.js, aws-fargate

I have a React + NextJS application that is hosted on a Fargate container. I have a custom lib file in the React app that needs to read the environment variables defined in the Fargate container task definition. I am using process.env. but it is coming out as empty. Here's a sample of how I am trying to read it:

`const API_KEY = process.env.API_KEY;`

I am trying not to use a .env since the environment variables are being defined in the Fargate container. Anyone has any idea why it would not work? Do I need to resort to .env file? If yes, then what's the purpose of being able to set the environment variable in the Fargate container?

Thanks.

Comment: Most likely is because you are trying to read the environmental variable in the client. 
React by default can only read `process.env` during the build time and not at runtime: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/ .

Could you please post a code snippet where you are reading the variable?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add at service name level in while creating services for AWS far-gate . one can do that Under Enviroment variables